# how to show a web page in modal after click

Tags: reactjs

i want to build a registration web page in react, that has a checkbox, and a text along that checkbox. one word in the text is a link to a pdf file which is the terms and conditions for example. now, how can i show that pdf not as a new window tab opened, but instead in the same tab and in a modal. i used the  tag with a href attribute but it opened for me a new tab, and i dont know how to get that the modal will open in the page, with like a href link that when the user click on that link (not a button. link) the modal will show.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show modal to user, set one state modal, something like this:

```
 const [modalConf, setModalConf] = useState({show:false, mode:''})
```

and user click the link, you can change the state, like:

```
setModalConf({show:true, mode:'Terms'})
```

and finally, you render the modal component like this :

```
<Modal show={modalConf.show} mode={modalConf.mode} />
```

and your modal component will get mode component from props:

Modal component:

```
props.mode === 'Terms' && render Terms

props.mode === 'Privacy' && render Privacy
```